# Create a section for high quality off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions

Create a section for high quality off-topic questions where questions like [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) may live.

Special rules:

- no reputation gain or limited reputation gain (to 1%?)
- hidden by default, with option to change this

Question may be moved to this section separately from closing/flagging, or in automatic way: all questions with a score higher than 30, closed as off-topic are placed there (30 is only a random number).

Comment: Hint: calling SO a "forum" has a strong tendency to get your question downvoted.

Comment: Why? How is this "high-quality"? Other than entertainment, what's the value?

Comment: Yeah, a "forum" section is *exactly* what we need. I was just wondering where I could go to get my daily fix of bad, off-topic, hyper-subjective questions. It's so tiring to see consistently high-quality, relevant, and useful questions all the time. ...Is this a joke?

Comment: Well, I've enjoyed that question, and some similar.  There ought to be somewhere where SE folks can get together and, er ... *chat* ... with like minded folks.  Alas, chat rooms don't quite work for ¿fun? polls either.

Comment: dupe [Should there be a new place where you could ask all the off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94982/)

Comment: Off topic questions, *by definition*, do not belong here, regardless of their quality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Simple explanation: Stack Overflow has a clearly declared scope, everything that's outside of this scope does not belong there. Your request sounds to me a lot like `Community Wiki` with additional limitations. But CW for questions has been removed for a reason, because it was used as an excuse for off-topic and/or subjective questions which simply do not belong here or do not serve a purpose.

But feel free to go to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and suggest/propose/support a new site were those things are on-topic.

Comment: I don't recommend proposing a new site. This Q&A format isn't really conducive to poll and discussion style questions; that's one of the reasons we don't allow them in the first place. Pushing them off on a new site won't fix the problem. We tried that once with Programmers when its definition was in its infancy.

Comment: True, but I never said that it was a good idea, but he's free to do so (especially if he can come up with a ***very*** good concept for such a site). I imagine that I had seen a similar proposal once, can't find it now, though.

Answer (score 3):

There already is a place to go to discuss off topic questions. It's called "A different site, where the subject is on topic".

Setting up an "area" for high quality off-topic questions would be rife with difficulty.

How do you decide the quality of an off-topic question to see if it meets your entry barrier. What subjective rules could you apply to deal with people who disagree with these decisions?