# Awareness of link spam

Tags: support, spam

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049085/how-to-find-the-car-on-lease (10k only now) was presented to the site about 15 minutes ago.  The original text contained a link to some fly-by-night, poorly constructed leasing website.

I purged the link, but at least 3 people (no doubt trying to be helpful) are trying to see what the OP wants.  Someone even upvoted the post.

I'm just wondering if there's some way to make people aware of this type of spamming.  Also, I know the site does something with links from new users (I'm not up on any SEO principles, so I don't remember what), but is it best to wipe out the link so it doesn't get crawled?

Comment: Yeah, the people who are going out of their way to be helpful here and ask for clarifying details are the same people who come to Meta and complain that *their* question got closed as off-topic, rant about how that is unfair, and then [propose we need a place to ask off-topic questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102104/create-a-section-for-high-quality-off-topic-questions). The only real question is ***why?***

Comment: @Cody I agree. However, I probably should have substituted the words "LINK SPAM WIPED" in the text, but in the off chance that I was missing something and it was legit, I'd rather let others infer the accusation.

Comment: I can't imagine why that got up-voted. But, well, I say that about posts that aren't SPAM too from time to time.

Comment: @Tim I don't know either.  Even without its filthy spammy content it wasn't a quality post to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I agree that you should have mentioned that you erased a spammy link. I'm frequently stunned to learn that the average SO participant has no idea how to view the revision history, or even knows how to tell that a post has been edited.

Comment: @Cody I'll definitely do that in the future.

Comment: @cody see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing I am also mystified why a 16k rep user upvoted that post.. I hope in error

Comment: @Jeff: I wasn't blaming the site for not informing users or making this clear, just citing my own anecdotal experience in encounters of the non-meta kind. If more people actually read the FAQ, we'd be far better off for more reasons than revision histories.